# Very different size of *.so and *.pyd, why?

Tags: python, python-extensions

I managed to build *.pyd library.  Sweat, blood, tears and gore aside, it turned out to be about 4 (four) times smaller than the corresponding *.so library.

While the code seems to work, I cannot help but to wonder why the difference is so huge.  Is there anything I should look out for?  I didn't add any debug / release / optimization settings to `Extension()` configuration, could this be the difference in defaults?

Comment: Does the pyd expose all features in the so ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust how would I know? They seem to do the exact same thing. By looking at the output of `dumpbin /all *.pyd` it seems like it has everything I could think of... Do you have any particular way of checking that?